# `isolcpus` kernel parameter has no effect on Ubuntu 16.04 desktop

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I added the following line to `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash isolcpus=1,3"
```

then ran `sudo grub-update` (and rebooted) but according to `top` processes are still being scheduled on CPU 1 and 3. What should I do about this?

**Things I was asked to add:**

```
nabeel@nabeel-Inspiron-3542:~$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-22-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=1e46ca65-843f-439a-8e2a-f5e666a03ffe ro quiet splash isolcpus=1,3 vt.handoff=7
```

Output of `top`:

```
PID USER      PR S P 
182 root      20 S 0 
183 root       0 S 0 
220 root      20 S 0 
223 root      20 S 0 
253 root      20 S 2 
261 root       0 S 0 
312 root     -51 S 0 
343 root       0 S 3 <-------- Processes being scheduled on CPU 1 and 3
347 root       0 S 1 <--------
373 root       0 S 2 
398 root       0 S 0 
474 root       0 S 2 
478 root      20 S 0 
548 systemd+  20 S 0 
632 avahi     20 S 2 
633 root      20 S 2 
642 root      20 S 0
```

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: @EightBitTony Yeah, I did.

Comment: Can you add the output of `cat /proc/cmdline` to your question?  And, show the output from `top` which shows which CPU's have processes on them.

Comment: @EightBitTony Done.

Comment: What are those two processes?  e.g. are they `kworker` or something similar?

Comment: I've found that ..
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash isolcpus=3,7"
... only works with grub2 on Skylake "client" (i.e. consumer devices)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would guess those two processes are `kworker` or another kernel task.

It appears that presently, `isolcpus=` only affects user space threads, and hence, kernel threads will show up on the isolated CPU's.

From the [RHEL documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-Performance_Tuning_Guide-CPU-Configuration_suggestions.html) (emphasis mine),

> **3.3.6.2. Isolating CPUs**
>
> You can isolate one or more CPUs from the scheduler with the isolcpus boot parameter. This prevents the
>   scheduler from scheduling any **user-space threads** on this CPU. Once a
>   CPU is isolated, you must manually assign processes to the isolated
>   CPU, either with the CPU affinity system calls or the numactl command.

Someone tried to [patch this behaviour](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/2218495), but as far as I can tell, it wasn't acked.

In summary, Ubuntu isn't ignoring the option, it's working as intended.  Whether it's working as desired is a different query.

Comment: You are right, they are kworker threads (and there are a lot of them), but doesn't that defeat the point of isolating a CPU?

Comment: It depends, but that's how the option works, so it is working as expected.